# Chrome Web Inspector 'find and replace' operation

Tags: javascript

I want to automate a certain activity using javascript. Namely, it is about selecting checkbox fields.

```
<button is="paper-icon-button-light" id="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" aria-label="  XYZ" focus-type="checkbox" tabindex="0">
      <div id="checkmark"></div>
    </button>
```

Selecting a checkbox changes the aria-checked attribute from false to true. For this purpose, I created the following code, which I do not want to act unfortunately.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/aria-checked=\"false\" /g, "aria-checked=\"true\"")
```

How to bite it?

Comment: `aria-checked` is just an accessibility attribute. To check the checkbox, I guess you have to click on the button